# How to copy URL on button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

I am trying to copy the current page URL in the text area on button click. Somehow I have tried but is not working.
http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAF25LWITXR5

```js
    function Copy() 
    {
        var Url = document.createElement("textarea");
        Url.innerHTML = window.location.href;
        Copied = Url.createTextRange();
        Copied.execCommand("Copy");
    }
```

```html
<div>
 <input type="button" value="Copy Url" onclick="Copy();" />
 <br />
 Paste: <textarea rows="1" cols="30"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Copy() 
            {
                    //var Url = document.createElement("textarea");
                    urlCopied.innerHTML = window.location.href;
                    //Copied = Url.createTextRange();
                    //Copied.execCommand("Copy");
            }
    </script>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Copy Url" onclick="Copy();" />
            <br />
          
            Paste: <textarea id="urlCopied" rows="1" cols="30"></textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Get the textArea object (from id) and use "innerHtml" istruction for put url in textArea

Answer (score 18):

No need to create new `textarea`. try to get existing `textarea` by giving some `id` ('url').

Here is the working example

```js
function Copy() {
  var Url = document.getElementById("url");
  Url.innerHTML = window.location.href;
  console.log(Url.innerHTML)
  Url.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Copy Url" onclick="Copy();" />
  <br /> Paste: <textarea id="url" rows="1" cols="30"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

You should not use `execCommand` anymore, is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), use the `Clipboard` API:

```
let url = document.location.href

navigator.clipboard.writeText(url).then(function() {
    console.log('Copied!');
}, function() {
    console.log('Copy error')
});
```

More on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

Answer (score 4):

Modified your code little bit and it's working.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Copy() 
        {
            var Url = document.getElementById("paste-box");
            Url.value = window.location.href;
            Url.focus();
            Url.select();  
            document.execCommand("Copy");
        }
</script>
<body>
<div>

    <input type="button" value="Copy Url" onclick="Copy();" />
    <br />

    Paste: <textarea id="paste-box" rows="1" cols="30"></textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, no extra `html` code is needed:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click", "#ShareButton", function (e) {
            $("body").append('<input id="copyURL" type="text" value="" />');
            $("#copyURL").val(window.location.href).select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            $("#copyURL").remove();            
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: went to automatically downvote a jQuery answer but then noticed the question was tagged "jquery". sorry about that...

Answer (score 2):

When the button is clicked select the content of #url  then copy it to the clipboard.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Copy Url" id="copy" />
    <br />
    Paste: <textarea rows="1" cols="30" id="url"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector("#copy").onclick = function() {
      document.querySelector("#url").select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
    };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function Copy() 
            {
                    //var Url = document.createElement("textarea");
                    urlCopied.innerHTML = window.location.href;
                    //Copied = Url.createTextRange();
                    //Copied.execCommand("Copy");
            }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Copy Url" onclick="Copy();" />
            <br />
          
            Paste: <textarea id="urlCopied" rows="1" cols="30"></textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```