# Copy address bar content to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

How can I copy the contents of the browser's address bar to the user's clipboard using javascript / jquery? I'm trying to make an extension for Chrome and Firefox which adds a hotkey for that.

I figured [F6] was an easy target for the hotkey because it already selects the contents of the address bar in both browsers. So I tried:

```
(function() {
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        // [F6] selects and copies address bar content.
        if (e.keyCode == 117){
            document.execCommand('copy');
        }
    });
})();
```

However this doesn't copy it. Next I tried to get the url trough `window.location.href`, but I still have to copy it to the clipboard. So far the methods I found for getting a variable into the clipboard involve adding elements to a page. Seeing as it's for an extension and not a website I would prefer it doesn't modify pages.

I'm new to javascript and extension development so I'm in the dark on how I should go about this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can do it inside an event page which is a hidden background page so you won't modify the web page. Use chrome.commands API to declare a hotkey, chrome.tabs API to get the URL, don't use content scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what is done here : [How to copy URL on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40958613/how-to-copy-url-on-button-click)
Maybe you will need an hidden field to put the url before copying it.